# scipy kstest, used on scipy lognormal distrubtion

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use scipy's kstest on some data, and a few different distributions. I got to testing my data against a log-normal distribution, and got confused so I made a test.

I am parameterizing the log normal by its own mean and standard deviation (instead of scipys version where `loc` is exponential of the corresponding normal mean and `s` is the standard deviation of the corresponding normal.) 
Explained here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html

I have written a function that takes in the my parameters, converts them to scipys parameters, and then samples. Here it is:

```
def lognormal_samples(M_y, Sig_y):

    m_x = (2*math.log(M_y)) - (.5)*(math.log(math.pow(Sig_y,2) + math.pow(M_y,2)))
    scale = math.exp(m_x)

    sigma2 = -2 * math.log(M_y) + math.log(math.pow(Sig_y,2) + math.pow(M_y,2))
    s = math.sqrt(sigma2)

    result = stats.lognorm(s, scale=scale).rvs(size=10000)

    return result, s, scale
```

To test I want to see if the ks statistic is near 0 if I fit these samples to a `scipy.stats.lognormal`. Here I try to do that:

```
def lognormal_test_of_ks_test():

samples, my_s, my_scale = lognormal_samples(1, .25)
ks = stats.kstest(samples, 'lognorm', args=[my_s, my_scale])[0]
print('ks: ', ks)
```

When I run this I get `ks: 0.958038612187` which is ridiculously high. My problem I believe is that when I pass `[my_s,my_scale]` to `args` these are not actually getting passed to `s` and `scale` in `lognorm` in `kstest`. How do I pass my two paremeters into `kstest` so that they actually parameterize `lognorm`? I would image it would be something like:

```
my_s = 's=' + str(my_s)
my_scale = 'scale=' + str(my_scale)
my_args = [my_s, my_scale]
ks = stats.kstest(samples, 'lognorm', args=my_args)[0]
```

But this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kstest ends up calling `lognorm.cdf` which takes the following arguments according to [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html):

```
cdf(x, s, loc=0, scale=1)
```

So you need to pass:

```
my_args = [my_s, 0, my_scale]
ks = stats.kstest(samples, 'lognorm', args=my_args)[0]
```

which outputs:

```
ks:  0.007790356168134116
```